# Getting form data from a dynamic component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I'm struggling a lot with Angular 4 (is pretty new to me)...

My problem:

I'm having a form and in this form the user can add some new fields (when he clicks on a btn) - and it can be any number of fields.
For that to be possible, I generate a new component in the form component (at every click).

I have in ts:

```
 export class FormComponent {
    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container:ViewContainerRef;

    // this fires on click of the use which wants to add some fields
    public addComponent() {
    @Component({templateUrl: './pathToHtml'})
    class TemplateComponent {}
    @NgModule({declarations: [TemplateComponent], imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule]})
        class TemplateModule {}

        const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
        const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
            comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
        );
        const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
        }
}
```

In html I have separate templates for each component - the FORM component and the TEMPLATE one.

Sample from  the form:

```
<form action="" (ngSubmit)="save(configHeadersForm.form)" #configHeadersForm="ngForm">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test" ngModel required/>
</form>
```

Sample from the template:

```
 <input type="text" name="test2" ngModel>
```

In the form class in **save** function (which fires on submit and should have the form data) if I print form.value (I put in the input fields 'asddffd'), I have:

```
 Object { "test": 'asddffd'}
```

So only the value from the FORM template, not also the one from the generated component (test2). Any ideas, pretty please?:)

Comment: you can use reactive forms and get the work done ,,i can suggest you to look into https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2 for better understanding

Comment: @vikk, requirement is quite different as it is dynamic component not dynamic forms. Which I am assuming OP wants to generate a specific component based on different use case.

Comment: oh understood that wrongly!

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work the correct way you have to implement `ControlValueAccessor`, alternatively another work around while able to use template driven on your child components is to create a directive.

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[provide-parent-form]',
   providers: [
   {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: function (form: NgForm) {
        return form;
      },
      deps: [NgForm]
   }
 ]
})
export class ProvideParentForm {}
```

Then on your component you would use the directive as follow (Needs to be at the root of your template before ngModel):

```
<div provide-parent-form>
   <input type="text" name="test2" ngModel>
</div>
```